# Django form encoding

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am sending data over to my view using a form. When I send the char ó it is printed in the view as the char �. Any idea how to have it encoded correctly?

views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def myView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            print(title) # prints � instead of ó
```

forms.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

myform.html:

```
<form action="/results/" method="post" content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>>{% csrf_token %}
  {{  form.non_field_errors }}
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.title.errors }}
      <label for="id_name">Title</label>
      {{ form.title }}
  </div>

  <button type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> Search
  </button>

</form>
```

Comment: The encoding you specify in your files is entirely different from the encoding of actual values handled by your code. That said, I suspect your terminal (i.e. what's actually doing the printing) just doesn't support displaying that character; have you tried passing that value back to a template and seeing whether the browser displays it correctly?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but the template shows the char in the same way as the terminal

Comment: I used your code almost exactly (with tweaks since it depends on code that isn't provided) and I can't reproduce this; the ó displays correctly in the terminal and the browser. Python 3.5.3, Django 2.1.2. Works as expected both with and without the file encoding declarations... whatever the problem is you're having, it seems to be with either your local environment or some part of the code that wasn't provided. Is the actual model `title` a standard CharField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding this to the html form:

```
accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

The correct form looks like this:

```
<form action="/results/" method="post" content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' accept-charset="UTF-8"> {% csrf_token %}
  {{  form.non_field_errors }}
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
  {{ form.title.errors }}
  <label for="id_name">Title</label>
  {{ form.title }}
  </div>

  <button type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> Search
  </button>

</form>
```

Comment: I'd be concerned that this was necessary (it's certainly not normal). Without further information, that this happened at all suggests to me that there is at least one problem or misconfiguration somewhere in your environment, and I'd be nervous about moving forward without finding it first.